# How to set breakpoints in Xcode for files with obscure file extensions?

Tags: xcode

I'm working on a project that uses Rust, so the files have an extension of `.rs`. Xcode won't let me set breakpoints. It seems it just handles the file as plain text. Is there any way to get it to allow me to set breakpoints in `.rs` files? One solution is to mark each `.rs` file as being some type of source code file that Xcode recognizes, e.g. an Objective-C source code file, but I'm looking for something that will apply globally to all `.rs` files.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode doesn't support Rust, and Rust files are plain text files for Xcode. Xcode debugger is just for C languages (C, C++, Objective-C) and Swift. Declaring .rs files as Objective-C only makes Xcode assume that they are Objective-C code.

You need a [Rust IDE](https://forge.rust-lang.org/ides.html) for debugging Rust code.

Comment: @meisel: Yes, `lldb` has support for many languages but Xcode hasn't.

Comment: To support rust for breakpoints, it just has to allow us to set breakpoints in .rs files. The syntax highlighting, etc. I can get from AppCode (but I'm interested in Xcode because AppCode uses Xcode's configuration files)

Comment: @meisel: So much for the theory, but it is unclear how tightly Apple has wired the file types in Xcode.

Comment: Yep, but worth asking

Comment: @meisel: But you shouldn't hang the messenger of bad messages either. ;)